# find values of a given recurrent

Tags: python, algorithm

Recurrent is given as f0 = 0, f1 = 1, f2 = 2 и fk = fk-1 + fk-3 , n and ki are also given.

I need to write a program that counts n numbers on ki position of a given recurrent

Example1 in

```
4
0 1 2 3
```

Example1 out

```
0 1 2 2
```

Example2 in

```
3
4 5 4
```

Example2 out

```
3 5 3
```

Here is my ideas

```
def get_numbers():
    with open('input.txt','r') as file_in:
        n = int(file_in.readline()[:-1])
        input_list = map(int,file_in.readline().split(' '))
        print(foo(n,input_list))

def find_number(n):
    a, b, c = 0, 1, 2
    for _ in range(n+1):
        yield a
        a, b, c = b, c, a + c

def foo(n,input_values):
    result = str()
    for elem in (list(find_number(i))[-1] for i in input_values):
        result += str(elem) + " "
    return result[:-1]

get_numbers()
```

I have tried to use generators to speed up my code, but can't get the idea of how to make it use less memory.

So I am trying to either make my code consume less memory or just find another (simpler) solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can utilize `functools.lru_cache` ([doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache)) to cache results of the recursive function:

```
from functools import lru_cache

@lru_cache(maxsize=None)
def f(k):
    if k < 3:
        return k
    return f(k-1) + f(k-3)

def f2(k):
    if k < 3:
        return k
    return f2(k-1) + f2(k-3)

from timeit import timeit

t1 = timeit(lambda: f(45), number=1)
t2 = timeit(lambda: f2(45), number=1)

print(t1)
print(t2)
```

Prints on my computer:

```
2.5337999886687612e-05
2.7258617150000646
```

For k=50 the difference is more bigger:

```
t1 = timeit(lambda: f(50), number=1)
t2 = timeit(lambda: f2(50), number=1)
```

Prints:

```
2.6389000140625285e-05
18.368431184999736
```

Answer (score 1):

It took some work, so it is going to be difficult to explain *all* I did. However, few things that I noticed in your original code were the relationship of function `foo` and `find_number`; also, function `foo` is doing lots of string operations, which are expensive.
I was able to come up with simplified code, and it works with the two sample inputs you provided. However, I can't test further than this. Hope it works for you.

```
# unchanged from yours.
def get_numbers():
    with open('input.txt', 'r') as file_in:
        n = int(file_in.readline()[:-1])
        input_list = map(int, file_in.readline().split(' '))
        print(foo(n, input_list))


# I removed the generator. I let the loop scramble
# the numbers, but only return the one bit that is
# relevant inside `foo`, which gets greatly simplified
def find_number(n):
    a, b, c = 0, 1, 2
    for _ in range(n):
        a, b, c = b, c, a + c
    return a

# With the change in `find_numbers` this gets much simpler
# which should help with speed and memory consumption  
def foo(n, input_values):
    return [find_number(i) for i in input_values]
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your inputm output or the 'n', but here is my idea: if f0, f1, f2 are defined your function must do something just if `k > 2` and fk when k < 2 is k.

I will call f0 as f(0), so:

```
def f(k):
    if (k < 2): return k
    return f(k-1) + f(k-3)
```

You can just do:

```
>>> f(4)
```

Comment: It is slow for big k

Comment: How big is your k?

Answer (score 0):

For a faster but havier code:

```
k = int(input('Enter a value for k: '))

f0 = 0
f1 = 1
f2 = 2

def calc(k):
    try:
        return eval(f'f{k}')
    except:
        kLessOne = k-1
        kLessThree = k-3
        try:
            eval(f'f{kLessOne}')
        except:
            globals()[f'f{kLessOne}'] = calc(k-1)

        try:
            eval(f'f{kLessThree}')
        except:
            globals()[f'f{kLessThree}'] = calc(k-3)

        return eval(f'f{kLessOne} + f{kLessThree}')

print(calc(k))
```

This code instantiates global variables at runtime, I don't recommend you to do this.